# 404 error on new pages but only for non logged in users?

Tags: 404-error, user-access

So. Issue as title. Have researched lots but am near insanity!

1. Have done all the 'Refresh permalink' thing
2. Have edited .htaccess(*) and put generic rewrite code and refreshed permalinks again - the code gets overwritten with the original .htaccess rewrite code though in FTP the 'date modified' on the .htaccess file doesn't change (!??!)

Tried adding new menu and new page from scratch - this also returns 404 unless logged in as a user.

Any ideas please?

(*) Original .htaccess code replaced with:

```
    ># BEGIN WordPress
    ><IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    >RewriteEngine On
    >RewriteBase /
    >RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    >RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    >RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    >RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    ></IfModule>
    ># END WordPress
```

...gets rewritten to:

```
  ># BEGIN WordPress
  ># The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
  ># dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
  ># Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
  ><IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  >RewriteEngine On
  >RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}] ##<--This line apparently gets added
  >RewriteBase /
  >RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  >RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  >RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  >RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  ></IfModule>
  ># END WordPress
```

Comment: WordPress say in the .htaccess file that `Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.` Any custom rules that you have should be before `BEGIN WordPress` or after `END WordPress`.

Comment: That Rewrite Rule for Authorization is being added by another plugin, I haven't seen that as part of a default WordPress installation.  Try disabling your plugins and re-activating them one at a time.

Comment: Thanks Tony. Your suggestion led to my solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted!

.htaccess and permalinks NOT the issue.

Found it by disabling all plugins one by one until I found a content access restriction plug-in that had somehow been misconfigured for non logged in users. I hadn't changed anything but there we are! Reconfigured and back up and running.